Cuda_thread privacy
//CUDA Code
if (comm < d_g.nodes) {
    for (int node = d_community_pos[comm]; node < d_community_pos[comm + 1]; node++) {
        for (int neighbor = d_g.out_col[d_community_list[node]];
             neighbor < d_g.out_col[d_community_list[node] + 1];
             neighbor++) {
            
            int n_neig = d_g.child_out[neighbor];
            int neig_comm = d_p.node_comm[n_neig];
            
            d_count[d_fake_ids[neig_comm]] += 1;
        }
    }
}

Each thread (i) in this code should create a new copy of d_count and that should not be visible to or should not be modified by other threads. but in my case all the 5 threads modify the same copy and keep adding on exiting values, how to solve this problem ?
I tried declaring d_count in local memory and it worked but on the small data, when i tested it on big data it does not work because there's a limit on local memory usage we cannot use more than 512KB memory for each thread,
I tried to make d_count zero for each i, it also did not work.
Any suggestions how to make d_count a private array for each thread without using local memory ?

1 2

2 options you could use here:
Option 1: Use cudaDeviceSetLimit to set a higher stack size. Example below:
__global__ void simpleKernel() {
    ...
}

int main() {
    // Set the stack size limit to 16 KB
    cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitStackSize, 16 * 1024);

    simpleKernel<<<1, 256>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

Option 2: Create an array in global memory with multiple instances of d_count, one for each thread. You can then access the appropriate value. The simplest way to index that array would be to use the block / thread as indexes (for example, with a 1-dimension launch, index gridIdx.x * blockDim.x + blockIdx.x).
However, for option 2, if you want to optimize the amount of memory used, you can index your array with SM / warp / thread identifiers, so that you do not have to allocate more elements in your array than there are threads concurrently running on your GPU. If you want to learn more on how to achieve this, you can refer to this section of the PTX ISA.

thanks for your comment. for the first option, array would be very very large , 2.8Million * 2.8 MIllion elements each element is 8 bytes.   For the second one its seems feasible, can you give me small example how to do that and what would be max limit ?

Oh in that case you might want to index your array on SM and warp IDs, so that the number of elements in your array is no larger than the number of threads concurrently running. I'll add that to my answer.
For cudaDeviceSetLimit, you can just call the line of code that's in the answer, and replace <larger size> with a larger size than your current limit. The limit depends on the amount of RAM available on your GPU.

can you edit my code ? and post here please. I am very new to CUDA coding. would b very helpful.

I can't edit your code since cudaDeviceSetLimit is a host-side CUDA API, so you need to invoke it before launching your kernel

I tried to add more information on the answer*, let me know if that helps, thanks!

Hmm how much memory would you need per thread?

for this specific dataset, 11.06 MB per thread.

do you know any other ways that just clear ups the d_count array for each iteration so that we get new information every iteration ?

@AugustDiamond 11 MiB per thread is just not feasible. Even a small GPU needs a few thousand threads simultaneously to run efficiently. That would be more than 10 GiB of GPU RAM just for this state! You need to find a different way to distribute your work or lower the memory requirement.

Alternatively have a sub-group of threads cooperate on the work currently one thread is doing.
